# how to update customer's billing address in magento2?

Tags: magento2

I want to update billing address:

```
$defaultBilling  = $this->_customerAccountManagement
            ->getDefaultBillingAddress($customerData->getId());
```

but `$defaultBilling` is is instance of `\Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Address` and doesnt have `save` method.

i tried via repository

`$this->_addressRepository->getById($defaultShipping->getId())`

but also a data model, not the model itself,
`_addressRepository` is injected in constructor as `\Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface`

what do i do wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had to use factory:

`$defaultBilling = $this->_addressFactory->create()->updateData($defaultBilling)->save();`